# Why doesn't leftJoin Knex query work and gives me an error?

Tags: mysql, express, knex.js

I have an endpoint that retrieves posts and in my MySQL queries I want to check if a user already liked it by left joining with likes table.

```
  const posts = await knex
    .from("posts")
    .select(
      "posts.id as id",
      "posts.text",
      "posts.user_id",
      "likes.user_id as liked",
      knex("comments")
        .count("*")
        .whereRaw("?? = ??", ["comments.post_id", "posts.id"])
        .as("comments"),
      knex("likes")
        .count("*")
        .whereRaw("?? = ??", ["likes.post_id", "posts.id"])
        .as("likes")
    )
    .leftJoin("likes", function () {
      this.on("likes.user_id", req.id).andOn("likes.post_id", "posts.id");
    });

  res.send(posts);
```

It gives me this error

> (node:96670) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '1' in 'on clause'

My req.id evaluates to 1, how can I left join with values instead of columns?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your schema, I'd expect you to be able to do something like this:

```js
const posts = await knex
  .select(
    "p.id as id",
    "p.text",
    "p.user_id",
    knex
      .raw("CASE WHEN l.user_id = ? THEN true ELSE false", [req.id])
      .as("liked")
  )
  .count("c.id as comments")
  .count("l.id as likes")
  .from("posts as p")
  .leftJoin("comments as c", "c.post_id", "p.id")
  .leftJoin("likes as l", "l.post_id", "p.id");
```

Note that the `whereRaw`s in your example aren't necessary, you can just use ordinary joins and count the resulting ids.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can tweak your join clause using `knex.raw`

```
leftJoin("likes", function () {
    this.on("likes.post_id", "posts.id").andOn( knex.raw("likes.user_id = "+ req.id));
});
```

Another way would be to use [`onIn`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-onIn)

```
leftJoin("likes", function () {
    this.on("likes.post_id", "posts.id").onIn("likes.user_id",[req.id]);
});
```